# Keyboard not responding after suspend

Tags: lock-screen

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 5378 laptop ..I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS . After suspend , for login I pressed the keys and it's not responding ...only keys like volume and brightness keys are working... I searched for solutions but I didn't get anything..
Someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm I'm having the same problem with an Dell Inspiron 5378.

Okay, so in the end, having had this problem for quite a while, I'm blaming the GDM lock screen. I've now changed to the LightDM lock screen, by downloading from Synaptic:

- lightdm
- lightdm-gtk-greeter [simple display manager (GTK+ greeter)]
- lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings

So far, so good. I've repeatedly tried to suspend, in various ways, from pressing suspend from the top-right menu, to closing the laptop-lid, and I haven't had any problems since. If I do, I'll come in here at update this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Only 16.04 LTS is certified for this laptop. Install that and it should work. Later versions arent fully working in my experience.