# Can't use laptop native keyboard to wake up from suspend mode

Tags: keyboard, suspend, power-management, asus

I was using my configuration of Ubuntu GNOME+i3 in a desktop than a created a backup image to transfer it to a laptop. At first I had some problems as the system not finding the WiFi adapter, but updating and upgrading fixed them.

The current problem I'm facing is that when suspending the system I can't use the internal laptop keyboard to wake it up. If I have my external USB keyboard plugged when entering the suspend mode I can use it to wake it up successfuly.

I've checked some other questions related to it as

- [Keyboard not working after suspend to ram (sleep)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38797/keyboard-not-working-after-suspend-to-ram-sleep)
- [Keyboard not responding after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144241/keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend)
- [Laptop will not wake from suspend with usb-keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385306/laptop-will-not-wake-from-suspend-with-usb-keyboard)
- [Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298198/ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend)

All the answers goes around changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, but I don't understand what this variable is changing. I just know that none of the answers helped me.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and a laptop Asus Vivobook 16x OLED M7600Q